# how do I make changes to a 2d array stick?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have looked up a few questions similar to this and have found nothing useful yet.

I am creating a board game and I am using 2d arrays. I am trying to add a "Room" object to a "Board" object.

Both room and board are 2d arrays. I am keeping them as String arrays and running through them in the draw method to show a position (which is a small part of the board).

I am trying to change the contents of the Board 2d array to include a Room 2d array.

this is the Board Class:

```java
public class Board {

    private String[][] board;

    public Board(int x, int y) {

        board = new String[x][y];

        for (int i = 0;i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                board[i][j] = "floor";
            }
        }
    }

    public void addToSquare(int x, int y, String item) {
        String currentItems = this.getFromSquare(x,y);
        currentItems.concat(item);
        board[x][y] = currentItems;
    }

    public void clearSquare(int x, int y) {
        board[x][y] = "";
    }

    public void addRoom(Room room, int centrePointX, int centrePointY) {

        for (int i = 0; i < room.roomX; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < room.roomY; j++) {

                String roomContents = room.getContents(i,j);
                int roomOriginX = room.radX;
                int roomOriginY = room.radY;
                this.clearSquare((centrePointX-2 + i), (centrePointY-2 + j));
                this.addToSquare((centrePointX-2 + i), (centrePointY-2 + j), roomContents);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getFromSquare(int x, int y) {
        return board[x][y];
    }

    public String[][] getShownPosition(int playerX, int playerY, int shownWidth, int shownHeight){

        String[][] shownPosition = new String[shownWidth][shownHeight];
        int radX = shownWidth / 2;
        int radY = shownHeight /2;

        for (int i = 0; i < shownPosition.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < shownPosition.length; j++) {

                if (!((playerX-radX)+i <0 || (playerY -radY)+j <0 || (playerX-radX)+i >= board.length || (playerY -radY)+j >= board.length)) {
                    shownPosition[i][j] = board[(playerX - radX) + i][(playerY - radY) + j];
                }else{
                    shownPosition[i][j] = "blackSpace";
                }
            }
        }
        return shownPosition;
    }

}
```

When I come to draw the position I run through "ShownPosition" and show an image based on the string.

It might not be the right way to do it but - up to the room part - everything works.

The issue is that the room doesn't show up. As you can see I have filled a whole room with "walls" just to make it simpler to see when it loads.

I added the "clearsquare" and "addtosquare" methods as previously I was saying board[x][y] = roomContents.

in my update method I have written

```java
shownPosition = mBoard.getShownPosition(player.boardx,
                                        player.boardy,
                                        shownBoardX,
                                        shownBoardY);
```

but no matter what I try I cant get a "room" to show.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're ignoring the result of `currentItems.concat(item);` in `Board::addToSquare`, so it never actually adds anything to it. It should be

```
public void addToSquare(int x, int y, String item) {
    String currentItems = this.getFromSquare(x,y);
    currentItems = currentItems.concat(item);
    board[x][y] = currentItems;
}
```

Also when it comes to two-dimensional arrays and coordinates, make sure that you are actually storing values and accessing them with *correct coordinates*. For example see what the following code generates:

```
for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
    System.out.println("\n");
    for(int y=0; y<5; y++){
        System.out.printf("%s,%s\t", x, y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 

1,0 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 

2,0 2,1 2,2 2,3 2,4
```

You may notice that the array is generated in a way where Y actually represents columns and X represents rows. In order to fix this issue in your code you'll need to generate each two-dimensional array in a reverse order, i.e. first iterate through the rows and then columns:

```
for (int j=0; j<y; j++){        // <- these two
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++){    // <-  lines
        board[i][j] = "floor";
    }
}
```

or switch the coordinates:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
        board[j][i] = "floor"; // <- here
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm I guess that will come into play later.. currently both arrays are the same length so it doesn't really make a difference. I can get it to show the floor but not a "room" object as in changing the "floor" to a "wall"

Comment: @litlee I've updated the answer, please read the first paragraph.

Comment: Ah I see! That seems to work now I thought there was something I wasn't ubderstanding about arrays but it was just something silly (seems to always be the way!) Thanks!

Comment: @litlee glad to hear that. If you could mark the answer as correct that would be helpful so the question doesn't remain unanswered. Thanks!